# Search query ignoring custom fields in search in search index

Tags: craft3, search, index

I have a site with around 300 entries and at least 50 custom fields. But I'm only getting results if the keyword(s) are part of the title field, I have the "Use this field's value as keywords" option checked on all my fields. Also, I tried the update search index command but it didn't work. I hope someone has a solution to this. below is my search query code.

Thank you.

```
{% set searchQuery = craft.app.request.getParam('q') %}
{% set entries = craft.entries()
   .search(searchQuery)
   .section('and, not referrals, not newsletterSubscribe')
   .orderBy('score').limit(15) %}
{% if entries | length %}
    <h3>Found {{ entries | length }} search results for 
    <span>{{searchQuery}}</span></h3>
    <div class="search-result__list ">
{% for entry in entries %}
    <div class="search-result__item">
    <h4><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></h4>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <p>Your search for “{{ searchQuery }}” didn’t return any results.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a queue runner that executes queue jobs?  The search index command only creates queue jobs to perform the indexing, they still need to be executed. Check Utilities -> Queue Manager to see if the queue jobs are actually being executed. If not, use `php craft queue/run` to execute all pending jobs or `php craft queue/listen` to create a queue runner that executes new jobs as they come in.

See the article [*Robust queue job handling*](https://nystudio107.com/blog/robust-queue-job-handling-in-craft-cms) for details.